# Is there a way to test Chakra-ui modal dialogs with react-test-renderer?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, chakra-ui, react-test-renderer

I'm desperately trying to test a modal but can't get my head around it!

This is where I'm at:

```
expect(
  create(
    <PortalManager>
      <Modal isOpen={true} onClose={jest.fn()}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>Modal body</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>Modal footer</ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </PortalManager>,
  ).toJSON(),
).toMatchSnapshot();
```

I forced the modal to be opened. I added the `PortalManager` around it to make sure Chakra knows where to place the modal but snapshot is always empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, an option may be to mock `PortalManager` itself and make it act like a `React.Component` instead of a `React.ReactPortal`, so something like

```
const divWithChildrenMock = (children, identifier) => <div data-testId={identifier}>{children}</div>;
const divWithoutChildrenMock = (identifier) => <div data-testId={identifier} />;

jest.mock("@chakra-ui/react", () => (
  {
    ...jest.requireActual("@chakra-ui/react"),
    PortalManager: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "portal")),
    Modal: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "modal")),
    ModalOverlay: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "overlay")),
    ModalContent: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "content")),
    ModalHeader: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "header")),
    ModalFooter: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "footer")),
    ModalBody: jest.fn(({ children }) => divWithChildrenMock(children, "body")),
    ModalCloseButton: jest.fn(() => divWithoutChildrenMock("close")),
  }
));
```

By looking at the following source file

https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/main/packages/modal/src/modal.tsx

You can see that even the modal components uses `Portal`, so, you should mock these components too, as in the example.

Test id is useful in the tests to check, in the snapshots, if all components are rendered in the right order.

Comment: It properly mocks the PortalManager as there is an additional div in the empty snapshot but the modal is still nowhere to be seen. There has to be a context or something behind it.

Comment: @Ploppy, check the edit and let me know if this make sense to you. You may need to do a custom function for `Modal` component, if you need to check props too.

Comment: This way it works properly, wonderful ! Thank you very much. I struggled for so long with this haha